# Streaming depth to web browser

Tags: asus-xtion-pro-live, mjpeg-server, ubuntu, jetson-tk1, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 on a Nvidia Jetson TK1, using an Asus Xtion Pro Live.

Is it possible to stream the depth from a primesense device to web browser? I understand that it is possible to stream the rgb to a web browser using mjpeg_server and openni2.

When I try to use mjpeg_server, and I subscribe to the topic `/camera/depth/image_raw`, mjpeg_server gives the error `Unable to convert 16UC1 image to ipl format`.

And when I subscribe to `/camera/depth/image`, mjpeg_server gives the error `Unable to convert 32FC1 image to ipl format`.

Can anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196309/streaming-depth-to-web-browser/) by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 324 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out my response to streaming the MJPEG stream of these topics in http://answers.ros.org/question/196270/stream-asus-xtion-pro-live-rgb-with-openni2-and-mjpeg_server/?answer=196334#post-id-196334.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-10-30**:
This is excellent! Also, I think you should move your answer from the link you provided to here instead! I think it's more relevant here. I noticed the quality parameter doesn't work. Will it be included soon?

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-10-30**:
I'm having difficulty trying to show this on my webpage using the img tag. Do you know what's wrong?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-10-31**:
What is the URL you are trying to pass in? It should be in the format http://localhost:8080/stream?topic=/IMAGE_TOPIC&param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3 Note the `&` after the first initial `?`

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-11-05**:
I'm actually trying to get the stream from a network device rather than localhost, so the URL looks something like `http://my.network.device.ip:8181/stream_viewer?topic=/camera/depth/image`.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-11-05**:
The `stream_viewer` URL will display an HTML page with the stream already embeded inside of it. To get it inside of an image element `src`, use `http://my.network.device.ip:8181/stream?topic=/camera/depth/image`

**Comment by [Andrew.A](https://answers.ros.org/users/5270/andrew.a/) on 2014-11-05**:
I'll try this out once I can, thanks!